# `Graphics3D` doesn't appear

Tags: graphics3d

I think that `z` values are very closed to each other. So, `Graphics3D` doesn't appear.

```
list={{{-5, -5, 0.126912}, {-5, -4, 0.128462}, {-5, -3, 0.130012}, {-5, -2,
    0.131561}, {-5, -1, 0.13311}, {-5, 0, 0.134657}, {-5, 1, 
   0.136204}, {-5, 2, 0.137748}, {-5, 3, 0.139292}, {-5, 4, 
   0.140834}, {-5, 5, 0.142373}}, {{-4, -5, 0.162526}, {-4, -4, 
   0.164015}, {-4, -3, 0.165499}, {-4, -2, 0.166978}, {-4, -1, 
   0.168451}, {-4, 0, 0.169918}, {-4, 1, 0.171379}, {-4, 2, 
   0.172833}, {-4, 3, 0.174281}, {-4, 4, 0.175723}, {-4, 5, 
   0.177157}}, {{-3, -5, 0.195412}, {-3, -4, 0.196719}, {-3, -3, 
   0.198017}, {-3, -2, 0.199303}, {-3, -1, 0.200579}, {-3, 0, 
   0.201842}, {-3, 1, 0.203095}, {-3, 2, 0.204335}, {-3, 3, 
   0.205564}, {-3, 4, 0.20678}, {-3, 5, 0.207984}}, {{-2, -5, 
   0.222664}, {-2, -4, 0.223665}, {-2, -3, 0.224649}, {-2, -2, 
   0.225618}, {-2, -1, 0.22657}, {-2, 0, 0.227506}, {-2, 1, 
   0.228425}, {-2, 2, 0.229327}, {-2, 3, 0.230212}, {-2, 4, 
   0.23108}, {-2, 5, 0.23193}}, {{-1, -5, 0.241484}, {-1, -4, 
   0.242067}, {-1, -3, 0.242631}, {-1, -2, 0.243174}, {-1, -1, 
   0.243698}, {-1, 0, 0.244201}, {-1, 1, 0.244684}, {-1, 2, 
   0.245147}, {-1, 3, 0.245589}, {-1, 4, 0.24601}, {-1, 5, 
   0.246411}}, {{0, -5, 0.24973}, {0, -4, 0.249827}, {0, -3, 
   0.249903}, {0, -2, 0.249957}, {0, -1, 0.249989}, {0, 0, 0.25}, {0, 
   1, 0.249989}, {0, 2, 0.249957}, {0, 3, 0.249903}, {0, 4, 
   0.249827}, {0, 5, 0.24973}}, {{1, -5, 0.246411}, {1, -4, 
   0.24601}, {1, -3, 0.245589}, {1, -2, 0.245147}, {1, -1, 
   0.244684}, {1, 0, 0.244201}, {1, 1, 0.243698}, {1, 2, 
   0.243174}, {1, 3, 0.242631}, {1, 4, 0.242067}, {1, 5, 
   0.241484}}, {{2, -5, 0.23193}, {2, -4, 0.23108}, {2, -3, 
   0.230212}, {2, -2, 0.229327}, {2, -1, 0.228425}, {2, 0, 
   0.227506}, {2, 1, 0.22657}, {2, 2, 0.225618}, {2, 3, 0.224649}, {2,
    4, 0.223665}, {2, 5, 0.222664}}, {{3, -5, 0.207984}, {3, -4, 
   0.20678}, {3, -3, 0.205564}, {3, -2, 0.204335}, {3, -1, 
   0.203095}, {3, 0, 0.201842}, {3, 1, 0.200579}, {3, 2, 
   0.199303}, {3, 3, 0.198017}, {3, 4, 0.196719}, {3, 5, 
   0.195412}}, {{4, -5, 0.177157}, {4, -4, 0.175723}, {4, -3, 
   0.174281}, {4, -2, 0.172833}, {4, -1, 0.171379}, {4, 0, 
   0.169918}, {4, 1, 0.168451}, {4, 2, 0.166978}, {4, 3, 
   0.165499}, {4, 4, 0.164015}, {4, 5, 0.162526}}, {{5, -5, 
   0.142373}, {5, -4, 0.140834}, {5, -3, 0.139292}, {5, -2, 
   0.137748}, {5, -1, 0.136204}, {5, 0, 0.134657}, {5, 1, 
   0.13311}, {5, 2, 0.131561}, {5, 3, 0.130012}, {5, 4, 0.128462}, {5,
    5, 0.126912}}};
    list1 = Flatten[list, 1];
symbols[{x_, y_, z_}] := {Red, Text["\[FivePointedStar]", {x, y, z}]}
Graphics3D[Map[symbols, list1]]
```

Comment: What are you trying to plot? It doesn’t appear that your syntax is correct (edit: but it does work), nor does the syntax you’ve attempted hint at what your goal is. Can you, please, edit your question and better inform on what your goal is; that is, what it is that you are trying to plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Graphics3D[Map[symbols, list1], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah you beat me, I’ll delete my answer! I think it would be valuable to explain why the setting of `BoxRatios` is needed to override the automatic scaling set by the relative scale of the components.